# How to restore the Visual Studio Compare/Merge tool?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, file-comparison, kdiff3

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017. I installed KDiff3 compare tool (version 0.9.98) in in my local machine. Now, by default, file comparison (.cs extension) in Visual Studio is happening in KDiff, unlike earlier when it used to open in the native Compare and Merge tool of Visual Studio. I want the previous tool back. Is there any way to change the default comparison tool for Visual Studio from KDiff3 to the TFS Compare and Merge tool?
I checked **Tools -> Options... -> Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server -> Configure User Tools** but nothing is configured here.

[image]

I googled this issue and I am getting multiple articles on how to configure a third party tool such as WinMerge or BeyondCompare for comparison but there are no articles on how to remove any existing tool to restore the original Visual Studio comparison tool. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the below steps to resolve the issue.

**Step1:** Click configure User Tools...
[image: Click configure user tools]
Go to
`Tools` `->` `Options`... `->` `Source Control` `->` `Visual Studio Team Foundation Server` `->` `Configure User Tools`

**Step2:** Click on Add...

[image: Click on Add]

Click on Add in Configure User Tools

**Step3:** Configure settings as shown in the image...

[image: Configure settings as shown in the image]

Configure the settings as shown in image.
Select the path in command field as
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\vsDiffMerge.exe`

Change path according to your system to point to vsDiffMerge.exe

Save the configuration. It should resolve the KDiff issue.